# Struggling with Turbolinks and CSP to render a partial

Tags: render, content-security-policy, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am using Rails 6.1.7 with turbolinks and CSP nonce based.

Here is my CSP config :

```
    policy.default_src :self, :https
    policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
    policy.img_src     :self, :https, :data
    policy.object_src  :none
    policy.script_src  :self, :https, "https://code.jquery.com/", "https://www.google-analytics.com"
    policy.style_src   :self, :https
    # If you are using webpack-dev-server then specify webpack-dev-server host
    policy.connect_src :self, :https, "http://localhost:3035", "ws://localhost:3035" if Rails.env.development?

Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = -> request do
    if request.env['HTTP_X_TURBOLINKS_NONCE'].present?
        request.env['HTTP_X_TURBOLINKS_NONCE']
    else
        SecureRandom.base64(16)
    end
end
```

Here is my application.js :

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:request-start", function (event) {
    console.log("in coming request");

    var xhr = event.data.xhr;

    xhr.setRequestHeader(
      "X-Turbolinks-Nonce",
      $("meta[name='csp-nonce']").prop("content")
    );
  });
};
```

What I want to achieve is to make an Ajax call to an endpoint in my controller (this part works) and then it would render a partial to only update a section of my actual page

Controller method:

```
def get_matching_labels
  @label= "test"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render layout: false}
  end
end
```

and I have a `get_matching_labels.js.erb` file which contains :

```
$('#my_frame').html("<%= j (render partial: 'frame_content', locals:{label: @label}) %>")
```

here is my Ajax call which is surrounded by `<%= javascript_tag(nonce: true) do %>`

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/get_matching_labels',
      headers: { 'HTTP_X_TURBOLINKS_NONCE' : '<%= content_security_policy_nonce %>'},
      data:{
        label: 'test',
      },
      complete: function() {
        console.log(this.headers);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('success')
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('failure')
      }
    });
```

As you can see I tried to pass my actual nonce as a header so my CSP would not generate a new one for that request and thus my script wouldn't be violating the CSP rules.

Note: I have a console.log on my Application.js but it never get triggered, it looks like the event I am trying to catch is not the right one.

Comment: For the ones who end up here from search engines, I finally achieved what I wanted by using JSON response format instead of JS.

```

Answer (score 1):

For the ones who end up here from search engines, I finally achieved what I wanted by using JSON response format instead of JS. As this doesn't trigger any CSP violation :

On my controller :

```
def get_matching_labels
  @labels = Label.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:label]}%")


  @html_content = render_to_string :partial => 'labels_autocomplete', :locals => { labels: @labels }

  render :json => { :html_content => @html_content }
end
```

Create an empty file named `get_matching_labels`

And put some regular html/erb in the `labels_autocomplete` partial